# Why leetcode gives the error'NameError: name 'longestCommonPrefix' is not defined...' when I have defined the function?

Tags: python

I'm new to python class when trying the longest common prefix problem on leetcode, I encountered the following error:

```
'NameError: name 'longestCommonPrefix' is not defined
    left = longestCommonPrefix(strs[0:idxl])
Line 9 in longestCommonPrefix (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().longestCommonPrefix(param_1)
Line 39 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 50 in <module> (Solution.py)'
```

Below is the code:

```
       class Solution:
        def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
            if(len(strs)==1):
                return strs[0]
            elif(len(strs)==2):
                return commonPrefix(strs)
    
            idxl = len(strs)//2
            left = longestCommonPrefix(strs[0:idxl])
            right = longestCommonPrefix(strs[idxl:])
            return commonPrefix([left,right])
    
        def commonPrefix(self,strs):
            print('strs:',strs)
            min_length = min(len(strs[0]), len(strs[1]))
            for i in range(min_length):
                if(strs[0][i]!=strs[1][i]):
                    return strs[0][0:i]
    
            return strs[0][0:min_length]
```

The code works find when running on my laptop without the class definition. However, when putting it under the class definition, it gives the error.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `left = self.longestCommonPrefix(...`?

Comment: You can also try the local run WITH the class, to do the exact same thing, you'll have the same error, you have to call the method on the object `self.longestCommonPrefix(...`

Comment: Adding 'self.' works, thanks!! @CristiFati